# How to add the spacing between the items in ListBox Wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have a ListBox which contains ListBoxItems, i have added the Buttons as the ListBoxItems in Vertical form.
the space between the buttons is set by margin.
But when i click below the button it was calling that event.

How should i remove that? And How can i set the height of the ListBoxItem & Margin to that Item?

Comment: What does "click below the button" means? you mean the `Margin` area.  Also, Share the code you tried.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ListBox.ItemContainerStyle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.itemcontainerstyle(v=vs.95).aspx) for Gets or sets the style that is used when rendering the item containers(`ListBoxItems`), Here Margin will do the required task for you: try the following code:

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="75"/>    <!-- For setting height of control-->
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="75"/>    <!-- For setting widthof control-->
      </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: i tried to set this before, but still when clicking the down area of the button it was clickable

Comment: I dont want to allow a clickable to that part, tried to set the Margin of ListBoxItem & Padding too,

Comment: **`<Style x:Key="ListBoxItemStyle" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="25"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="75"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="75"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>

            </Setter>

        </Style>`**